# How To change Quantity with ajax asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have a basket that has products. I'm trying to increase quantity by clicking (+)button with ajax here the code ;

my ajax code ;

```
function sepeteEkle(id) {
      var urunid = id;
      var sessionId = Session.SessionID;
      $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          url: "/Admin/WebService/Control.asmx/QuanInc",
          data: "{'urunid':'" + urunid + "','sessionId':'" + sessionId + "' }",
          success: function () {
              $("#AllCheckOut").load("CheckOut.aspx #AllCheckOut");
          },
          error: function () {
          }
      });
      return false;
  }
  $(document).on('click', '.QuaIncrease', function () {
      var nId = $(this).data("id")
      sepeteEkle(nId);
  });
```

and here is my repeater ;

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="repBasketDetail" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="cart_table_item">
                    <!-- Remove from cart link -->
                    <td class="product-remove">
                        <a href="http://stylo.senseithemes.com/?page_id=16&amp;remove_item=8d3bba7425e7c98c50f52ca1b52d3735&amp;_n=2e5bf0b319" class="remove" title="Remove this item">×</a>                        </td>

                    <!-- The thumbnail -->
                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <a href="ShopDetail.aspx?Id=<%#Eval("Id")%>" ><img width="100" height="130" src="<%#Eval("ProductPic") %>" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="T_7_front"></a>                     </td>

                    <!-- Product Name -->
                    <td class="product-name">
                        <a href="ShopDetail.aspx?Id=<%#Eval("Id")%>"><%#Eval("ProductName") %></a>                          
                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <!-- Product price -->
                        <div class="product-price">
                            <span class="amount"><%#Eval("ProductPrice") %> TL</span>                           </div>
                    </td>

                    <!-- Quantity inputs -->
                    <td class="product-quantity">
                        <div class="quantity buttons_added"><input type="button" value="-" class="minus"><input type="number" name="cart[8d3bba7425e7c98c50f52ca1b52d3735][qty]" step="1" min="" max="" value="<%#Eval("ProductQuantity") %>" size="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" maxlength="12"><input type="button" class="QuaIncrease"  data-id=<%#Eval ("Id") %> value="+" ></div>                     </td>

                    <!-- Product subtotal -->
                    <td class="product-subtotal">
                        <span class="amount">


                            <%# Eval("ProductPrice") %>
                        </span>                                        </td>
                </tr>
             </ItemTemplate>
```

and here is my webservice to increase ;

```
[WebMethod]
    public void QuanInc(int urunid, string SessionID)
    {
        using (Models.DermabonEntities db = new Models.DermabonEntities())
        {
            var product = db.Product.Find(urunid);
            if (product != null)
            {
                var userIp = SessionID;


                Basket basket = db.Basket.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userIp && x.ProductId == urunid);
                if (basket != null)
                {

                    basket.ProductQuantity++;

                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

    }
```

So I dont have login things. I create random session numbers and letters to get user per browser. 
urunid = producId which comes from product table. So right now im trying to get quantity increased 1 by 1 per click of the (+) value button as u see in repeater. But it does not work I will also need to decrease

```
mySessionId = '<%=Session.SessionID%>';
      alert(mySessionId);
```

So I can alert the session But still cant increase quantity

Comment: what do you mean by its not working, is the call not reaching the web method or is the DB changes not happening ?

Comment: Well nothing happens no error but nothing changes in database

Comment: I'm using almost same code for add to cart button and it increases the quantity but here it doesnt.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint, you don't see /Admin/WebService/Control.asmx/QuanInc get called?

Comment: did you check if the ajax request is reaching your web method.also check if anything error msg is returned in error block of ur ajax call, i can see that its empty now, change it like this ` error: function (msg) { console.log(msg);}`

Comment: I seted breakpoint to ajax code and webservice code but nothing happens

Comment: well then check the target url in ajax call, see through that ajax call reaches success block or error block anytime. any specific reason why your returning false in your function ?

Comment: every time i click the button it says Uncaught ReferenceError: Session is not defined  in the console of browser as i said I'm also using kinda same thing for add to card button and it works

Comment: you can't write .NET properties directly in javascript, you need to tell the compiler that those are .NET properties and not javascript: `var sessionId = '<%= Session.SessionID %>';`

Comment: still not working getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null plugins.js?ver=1:30
NLForm plugins.js?ver=1:30
(anonymous function) plugins.js?ver=1:186
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function custom.js?ver=1:106
(anonymous function) custom.js?ver=1:106
c jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:3
p.fireWith jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:3
x.extend.ready jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:3
q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the `Session.SessionID` is something coming from asp script, hence you need to enclose them in asp tags like this

```
mySessionId= '<%=Session.SessionID%>';
```

instead of

```
 var sessionId = Session.SessionID;
```

due to this the control is never reaching to your ajax call and you would know further process flow of it.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null plugins.js?ver=1:30
NLForm plugins.js?ver=1:30
(anonymous function) plugins.js?ver=1:186
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function custom.js?ver=1:106
(anonymous function) custom.js?ver=1:106
c jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:3
p.fireWith jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:3
x.extend.ready jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:3
q    getting these now

Comment: I can get id of the session now but still nothing happens with quantity. Any idea why it doesnt work ? I dont think something wrong with the webservice code

Comment: @user3703153: there are two things you check 1. Pass the data to remote service in your ajax request like this ,`var urunId = id;
      var sessId = Session.SessionID;
$.ajax({  ...,
data: {urunid:urunId,sessionId:sessId} });` 2. try given absolute url instead of relative url in the ajax request.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the network sniffer in browser developer tools (F12 on IE and Chrome, Firebug on Firefox), or Fiddler, and run this code.  Are you getting a 404 or 500 error when calling /Admin/WebService/Control.asmx/QuanInc?  It's possible the path to this service method is invalid (404), or the call to the service is erroring out (500).

Comment: everytime i click the button it says Uncaught ReferenceError: Session is not defined

Comment: Change your JS to read <%=Session.SessionID%>.  Your JS is thinking Session is a defined object, which it isnt.  This also assumes that the JS is directly on your ASP.NET ASPX file, if you have this JS code on a separate .js file, then this gets a little more tricky..

Comment: like this ;   var sessionId = <%=Session.SessionID%>

Comment: Oh.. and do this point, if you get this working, I DO NOT recommend you put a user session ID in client side markup, it's how session hijacking occurs... if you need to go this route, encrypt the value and store in a hidden variable or something, then pass THAT value and decrypt when your service method is called..

Comment: Okay gonna keep that in mind. gonna try to hide after this is done